# Meaning of verb-てまで

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

I've seen from [this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11073/meaning-of-sentence-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) and other sources that verb-てまで means "to the point of verb" or "to the extent of verb". But I can't make this work in the phrase below.

> 必死で努力してまでほめられるの...
>
> being praised to the point of being frantic and making effort.

From the context I think it should be talking about being frantic and making effort so that he can get praise.

Is there another interpretation of verb-てまで that makes more sense here?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think your interpretation is backwards, and that the idea is "being praised enough that x will work as hard as possible" or something like that. Someone more knowledgeable could correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To approach it from a different angle, it may be useful to know that 〜してまで is about **weighing the *worth* of actions**. Often the whole construct is negated, meaning that Y is not worth X:

> [X してまで Y する] 〜ない
>   *Y is not worth doing X*

---

### Breakdown: Negated example

> お金を払っ**てまで**食べようとは思わ**ない**
>   *I don't feel like eating it to the extent of paying money.*

You're actually weighing two things, and saying that 食べる is not worth お金を払う:

> [**お金を払う** してまで **食べる**] 〜ようとは思わない

---

### Breakdown: Non-negated example

> 命をかけ**てまで**助けてくれた
>   *They saved me, to the point of risking their life.*

Here, the rescuer weighed the two things, and decided that 助ける was worth 命をかける:

> [**命をかける** してまで **助ける**] 〜してくれた

---

### 必死で努力してまでほめられる

I'm not sure about the context of the ellipsis in your example, but even from that stub you can parse the overall sentiment as:

> ほめられる is not worth 必死で努力する

The ellipsis could signify a question (*Is getting praise worth making a frantic effort…?*), or disapproval (*Wow, making a frantic effort for praise…*). Or it could actually be a non-negated statement, like “必死で努力してまでほめられるの**が好き**!” (*I like getting praise so much that it is worth a frantic effort!*).