# What does いくら mean with 時間がない?

Tags: translation

I found it in several sites like this: https://daigakujc.jp/c.php?u=00325&l=05&c=00686

My question is what "いくら時間がない” means.

I've only been taught how to use いくら with でも.

I only understand right now "no matter how much time we don't have." But that doesn't sound logical so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: However little time we have.

Answer (score 3):

You're not parsing the sentence correctly, I'm afraid.

> でも、**いくら**時間がない**といっても**０ではありません。

「いくら～～ても」 means "No matter how much ~~" or "Even though ~~".
「いくら～～と言っても」(≂「いくら～～とはいえ」) literally means "No matter how much (one) say ~~". It can more naturally translate to "It is true that ~~, but" or "Even though it is true that ~~".

> いくら時間がないと言っても...
> "Even though it is true that you have little time, ..."

---

An example from [another website](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82-to-ittemo/):

> 私たちは夜の間どこかに隠れることを考えなくちゃ。**いくら**武装してる**といっても**、結局三人しかいないんだからね。
> We ought to think of taking cover somewhere for the night. After all we’re only three, even if we are armed.

This post may also help:

- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11082/9831